# How to do grep even if the file is not present?

Tags: shell-script, files, grep, ksh

I am doing something like this in my code

```
file_nm=`ls -latr *abc*`
if [ `grep "search_txt" "$file_nm" | wc -l` -gt 0 ]
then
  echo "string found"
else
  echo "string not found"
fi
```

If the `file_nm` is resolved blank, my code hangs as the `grep` is expecting the `file_nm` which is blank.  How can I make this code work?  Is there any option in `grep` to bypass the command if the file doesn't exist?

Comment: Can you please edit the question to fix your markdown surrounding the command you're running?  I also believe you're missing an opening quote around $file_nm

Comment: There are several problems with your question, not least of which, the code you posted doesn't hang.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
grep "search_txt" /dev/null "$file_nm"
```

Feeding `/dev/null` to `grep` will make it work even if `$file_nm` is not existed, because `grep` always has at least one file - which is `/dev/null` - to work on.

Comment: Are you sure this works if the blank variable is surrounded with quotes `""`?

Comment: @geedoubleya: Yes, of course. `grep` will return an error with file named space `" "`. `/dev/null` will help for the case when variable is empty `""`.

Answer (score 3):

You could simplify this significantly (and avoid the [nasty problems](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) inherent in parsing ls) by doing something like:

```
file_nm=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*abc*");
[ -e "$file_nm" ] && grep -q "search_txt" "$file_nm" &&
      echo "string found" ||
      echo "string not found"
```

However, like your original example, that will fail if you have more than one file matching `*abc*`. So, instead, I would use this:

```
for i in *abc*; do 
    grep -q "search_txt" "$i" && 
        echo "string found in $i" || 
        echo "string not found in $i"
done
```

If you don't care about matches in multiple files and just want to know if any of the files matching `*abc*` contain the string `search_txt`, you can simply do

```
grep -q "search_txt" *abc* &&  echo "string found" || echo "string not found"
```

Comment: A platform with ksh usually doesn't have `find -maxdepth`. Using `find` instead of `ls` doesn't really help anyway (it does help over using `ls -l` of course).

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems, including:

- Your code as posted doesn't hang
- You use the `-l` flag to `ls`, which means you'll be looking for files named `-rw-r--r--` and such
- You should avoid parsing the output of `ls` at all

And there's no need to test the output of `grep`, you can just use the exit status.  From `man grep`:

```
 EXIT STATUS
       The exit status is 0 if selected lines are found, and 1 if not found.
```

Here's a simplified version that does the same thing:

```
if grep -q "search_txt" *abc*
then
  echo "string found"
else
  echo "string not found"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You should [test if `$file_nm` is empty](https://serverfault.com/questions/7503/how-to-determine-if-a-bash-variable-is-empty) before running the grep

```
if [ -n "$file_nn" ];
```

will return True if $file_nm is NOT empty.

Comment: `test -f "$file_nm" && grep -q "$search_txt" "$file_nm"`